# How to download files from Docusign api using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

How to download files once signed by all using vb.net. I manged to send envelope with template id.So i want to get back that file using envelope id, pls provide some sampe code to retrieve back files using vb.net.

Here code what i used in vb.net

```
Private Function DoWnload(ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal basePath As String, ByVal accountId As String, ByVal envelopeId As String, ByVal documents As List(Of EnvelopeDocItem), ByVal docSelect As String) As String
    Dim config = New Configuration(New ApiClient(basePath))
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim envelopesApi As EnvelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(config)
    Dim results As System.IO.Stream = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docSelect)
    Dim docItem As EnvelopeDocItem = documents.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) docSelect.Equals(d.DocumentId))
    Dim docName As String = docItem.Name
    Dim hasPDFsuffix As Boolean = docName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".PDF")
    Dim pdfFile As Boolean = hasPDFsuffix
    Dim docType As String = docItem.Type

    If ("content".Equals(docType) OrElse "summary".Equals(docType)) AndAlso Not hasPDFsuffix Then
        docName += ".pdf"
        pdfFile = True
    End If

    If "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        docName += ".zip"
    End If

    Dim mimetype As String

    If pdfFile Then
        mimetype = "application/pdf"
    ElseIf "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        mimetype = "application/zip"
    Else
        mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
    End If
    ''Dim f1 As FileStream = New FileStream("sample.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    '  Return File(results, mimetype, docName)

    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte

    Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\File.pdf", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Do
            bytesRead = results.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If bytesRead > 0 Then
                outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            End If
        Loop While bytesRead > 0
    End Using
    Return ""

End Function



   Dim envelopeDocItems As List(Of EnvelopeDocItem) = New List(Of EnvelopeDocItem) From {
New EnvelopeDocItem With {
    .Name = "Combined",
    .Type = "content",
    .DocumentId = "combined"
},
New EnvelopeDocItem With {
    .Name = "Zip archive",
    .Type = "zip",
    .DocumentId = "archive"
}
```

in that docSelect what need to pass ? i passed documetid, getting error.

Regards,
Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Function DoWork(ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal basePath As String, ByVal accountId As String, ByVal envelopeId As String, ByVal documents As List(Of EnvelopeDocItem), ByVal docSelect As String) As FileStreamResult
    Dim config = New Configuration(New ApiClient(basePath))
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim envelopesApi As EnvelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(config)
    Dim results As System.IO.Stream = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docSelect)
    Dim docItem As EnvelopeDocItem = documents.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) docSelect.Equals(d.DocumentId))
    Dim docName As String = docItem.Name
    Dim hasPDFsuffix As Boolean = docName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".PDF")
    Dim pdfFile As Boolean = hasPDFsuffix
    Dim docType As String = docItem.Type

    If ("content".Equals(docType) OrElse "summary".Equals(docType)) AndAlso Not hasPDFsuffix Then
        docName += ".pdf"
        pdfFile = True
    End If

    If "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        docName += ".zip"
    End If

    Dim mimetype As String

    If pdfFile Then
        mimetype = "application/pdf"
    ElseIf "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        mimetype = "application/zip"
    Else
        mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
    End If

    Return File(results, mimetype, docName)
End Function
```

You will need to get the nuget from here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/ but version 5.0.0 won't work with the code above, use version 4.3

Update: adding this additional class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Namespace Models
    Public Class EnvelopeDocItem
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Type As String
        Public Property DocumentId As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting error in code,
screenshot : http://prntscr.com/ue2rpy
                    http://prntscr.com/ue2s9g
i installed docusign api 4.3 with .net framework 4.5 and i imported this namespaces
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Api
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client

Comment: You need to include System.Linq as well at the top in the list of namespaces

Comment: Hi, i am still getting error in code level, i added system.linq and i changed .net framework 4.6 also, but still showing error.

Comment: you will also need to add System.IO

Comment: I also added another class called EnvelopeDocItem for you, updated my answer

Comment: hi, i included following namespace
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Api
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Model
Imports System.Linq
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.MvcPrivate
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

still getting error in return value--http://prntscr.com/ufbkur

Comment: above i attach screenshot of error  - https://prnt.sc/ufbkur

Comment: You can import System.Web.MVC as well. Or you can change the code not to use this line.

Comment: hi , yes i removed line which used by MVC, and not  sure what value need to pass for docSelect ? above in my question i updated code also, i am getting following error 
Ss -- http://prntscr.com/umfafs , http://prntscr.com/umfbzl , i am used docusign dll 3.0.0 version for .net framework only

Comment: You are getting a 404, try to find out what URL/endpoint is being called, you may need a debugger or fiddler or some other tool to know that.

Comment: Yes i found the problem in basepath forgot to add /restapi at the end  and in docselect i pass "combined", Thanks a lot , now can download files using .net framework as well as.